# Syntax editor control does not refresh UI when data source is changed

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

I am using RadSyntaxEditor to achieve functionality such as showing some overloading of function. But I have a problem when I need to change `overloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems` with new OverloadInfoCollection, UI part is not changed. I assume that this change doesn't fire `INotifyPropertyChanged`, and that is a reason why UI is not updated. In a case, we change `overloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems` like in a `radButton1_Click` event handler, there is no change until I use the arrows button on the keyboard (probably that is a time where is INotifyPropertyChanged event is fired). I was trying to do some workaround, and that was a case where I tried to clear `this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems` but in that case, I got NullReferenceException even if instance is not null.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinForms.Controls.SyntaxEditor.UI;
using Telerik.WinForms.Controls.SyntaxEditor.UI.IntelliPrompt.Overloading;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            OverloadInfoCollection overloadListA = new OverloadInfoCollection { new OverloadInfo("aaa", "aaa description") };
            this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems = overloadListA;
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems.Clear();
        }

        private void btnChange_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OverloadInfoCollection overloadListB = new OverloadInfoCollection { new OverloadInfo("bbb", "bbb description") };

            OverloadListPopup overloadListWindow = this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow;
            overloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems = overloadListB;
            overloadListWindow.Refresh();
        }

        private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OverloadInfoCollection overloadListC = new OverloadInfoCollection { new OverloadInfo("ccc", "ccc description"), new OverloadInfo("ccc 1", "ccc 1 description") };
            this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow.Presenter.OverloadListItems = overloadListC;
        }

        private void radSyntaxEditor1_DocumentContentChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinForms.SyntaxEditor.Core.Text.TextContentChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.radSyntaxEditor1.SyntaxEditorElement.IntelliPrompts.OverloadListWindow.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Image with initial overload list]
[image: Image after click on radButton1_Click and change selection with arrow]

Answer (score 0):

Nenad,

This seems to be a known issue with RadSyntaxEditor from the Telerik UI for WinForms suite. You can track its progress, subscribe for status changes and add your comments on the following link: https://feedback.telerik.com/winforms/1477890-radsyntaxeditor-changing-the-overloadinfocollection-doesn-t-update-the-ui